# Laravel 4 handling 404 errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and I'm trying to catch any requests that do not match existing routes. Currently I am getting a ...

> `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

I have created an `App::missing()` handler in the `app/start/global.php` as described [on the documentation page](http://four.laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors) but that doesn't help. I also tried creating an `App::error(function(NotFoundHttpException $exception, $code)` handler, but that didn't help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which error were you getting when you tried editing global.php with the `App::missing()` method?

Comment: The error has not changed.

Comment: You sure you've turned off the detailed error reporting?!

Comment: I meant the error is always the same Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

dev/site/bootstrap/compiled.php
            $value = new Response($value);
        }
        return $value->prepare($request);
    }
    protected function handleRoutingException(\Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage());
        } elseif ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedException) {
            $allowed = $e->getAllowedMethods();

Comment: can you show the code, so that we can try to help you

Comment: Setting debug to false in app.php did not help. Here's the App::missing() defined in the global.php:

> App::missing(function($exception) {
>     die("HERE");
> });

I expect to see a "HERE" text, but instead of an error now (after turning the debug off) I see this message: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's likely due to debugging being turned on in the `app/config/app.php` file. Try turning that value to `false` and see if your custom handler than 'handles" it.

Additionally, your error handler needs to return a Response in order to "short-circuit" the request and actually respond with the result of your error handler - Are you returning a value / Response class from your `App::error()` handler? (Please show us that code).

Here's an article on [Laravel 4 Error Handling](http://fideloper.com/laravel4-error-handling) without outlines the process of how Laravel uses `App::missing()` and `App::error()` handlers when errors occur.

Pay specific attention to the "meat of the Handler class" section - it outlines how you need to return a value of some sort from the handler in order for it not to pass the Exception to the next handler (Likely your Whoops error output that displays when `debug` is set to `true` in `app/config/app.php`).

Comment: Setting debug to false in app.php did not help. Here's the App::missing() defined in the global.php:

`App::missing(function($exception) {
  die("HERE");
});`

I expect to see a "HERE" text, but instead of an error now (after turning the debug off) I see this message: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Answer (score 20):

You need this: In 'app/start/global.php' add:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
 {
     return Response::view('errorView', array(), 404);
 });
```

And of course in views create (in this case) errorView.blade.php
EDIT: This method handle all "404 Not Found" errors.

Comment: The key point, as stated above, being that you need to return a Response object (or more specifically, a non-null response).

Comment: While this solution works, the proper 404 headers (or different) are not sent to the browser.

Comment: For the proper 404 header to be sent, write return Response::view('errorView', array(), 404);

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to throw a 404 error when a ModelNotFoundException occurs

```
App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception, $code)
{
    return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in

### app -> config -> app.php

if you make

```
'debug' => true,
```

to this

```
'debug' => false,
```

You will get an user experience environment which is other than the debugging mode. Please make sure you have checked it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it works using the following code. I let 'debug' => true, in my local configuration.

In app/start/global.php

```
App::error(function(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    $response = Response::make(View::make('response')
        ->with('data', null)
        ->with('meta', 'Error, incorrect path')
        ->with('pagination', null));

    $response->setStatusCode(404);
    $response->header('content-type', 'application/json', true);

    return $response;
});
```

If of any interest, the content of my view is

```
<?php 

    echo json_encode(array(
    'data' => $data,
    'pagination' => $pagination, 
    'meta' => $meta), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 

?>
```

The main challenge was to use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException as the type of the Exception and not only NotFoundHttpException.

By using NotFoundHttpException, a 500 error was thrown.